# Fermat's eleventh $F_{11}$ represented as sums of two squares?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

There's an unanswered quest in another forum, that makes me sleepless: [Fermat's Elevnth](http://mymathforum.com/number-theory/328061-fermat-s-eleventh.html)

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N^{+}}$ and $a>b$ then,

there are $k$-representations for $F_{11}=2^{2^{11}}+1$ as sum of two squares: $ a_{1..k}^{2}+b_{1..k}^{2}$

1.) Find $k$.

2.) Find $a_{1..k}, b_{1..k}$.

Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, isn't it true that
$$2^{2^{11}} + 1 = \left(2^{2^{10}}\right)^2 + 1^2?$$

Comment: This is true and one of the possible representations.

Comment: @Peter: i only argee if all factors satisfy $\equiv 1 (mod 4)$. That is true for all Fermat factors. So your answer is right :)  $k=2^{n-1}$ is correct for Fermat numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the nature of the complete factorization. Evidently $F_{11}$ is odd,squarefree and has exactly five prime factors $p,$ each of which satisfies $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$

http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html#Summary

You do not need to know the specific primes, just the number. So there are 16 expressions as ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of positive numbers, $F_{11} = x^2 + y^2$

Oh, the numbers $(x,y)$ are enormous.

http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html

> F11 = 319489 · 974849 · 167988556341760475137 · 3560841906445833920513
>   · P564

That is enough information to do it all. You can get a computer to specify the prime called $P564$ by getting it to calculate $F_{11},$ carefully typing in the four prime factors given above, then divide them out of $F_{11},$ the final quotient will be the desired $P564.$ As I said in comment, after early progress, this was finished by Richard P. Brent, and $P564$ was proved to be prime by F. Morain, all in 1988.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The trivial solution $2^{2^{11}} + 1 = \left(2^{2^{10}}\right)^2 + 1^2$ is a member of this 16 solutions!

Comment: Yes, it is. $1$ is small, but the other number is large.

Comment: @Athlontiger, if you are given a fairly large prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ do you know (A) how to solve $t^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p?$ and (B) how to solve $x^2 + y^2 = p$ in integers? If you can do that for each of the five primes, you can use the hint of Peter to finish the job. You would need the actual five prime factors of $F_{11},$ of course, I am not sure where you would find those.

Comment: @Athlontiger alright, apparently Richard P. Brent found all prime factors in 1988, and the primality of one of them was proved in the same year in a doctoral dissertation in French by Morain. It is therefore likely that websites owned by Brent or, at least, his department, list all the prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : If you have $p=a^2+b^2$ and $q=c^2+d^2$, then you have
       $$pq=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad-bc)^2+(ac+bd)^2$$

and also $$pq=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad+bc)^2+(ac-bd)^2$$

Comment: Peter, I found the prime factors on a website F11 = 319489 · 974849 · 167988556341760475137 · 3560841906445833920513 · P564